# Why some decimal places truncated when insert 1234567890.12345678 into Decimal(18, 8) column in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite

Below is my table create in SQLite database,

```
CREATE TABLE MyData(
  Code VARCHAR(20),
  Amount DECIMAL(18, 8)
);
```

then I insert 2 rows into the table.

```
INSERT INTO MyData
VALUES('A', 1.12345678);

INSERT INTO MyData 
VALUES('B', 1234567890.12345678);
```

After that, execute a SELECT statement,

```
SELECT * FROM MyData;
```

SQLite returns the following result:

```
A|1.12345678
B|1234567890.12346
```

The DECIMAL(18, 8) suppose means precision=18 and scale=8, why some decimal places are truncated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The details of how sqlite stores its data is described [here](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).  When you specify the DECIMAL column type, the storage for the column has NUMERIC affinity.

Section 2.0 has the following description about type affinity:

> A column with NUMERIC affinity may contain values using all five
>   storage classes. When text data is inserted into a NUMERIC column, the
>   storage class of the text is converted to INTEGER or REAL (in order of
>   preference) if such conversion is lossless and reversible. For
>   conversions between TEXT and REAL storage classes, SQLite considers
>   the conversion to be lossless and reversible if the first 15
>   significant decimal digits of the number are preserved. If the
>   lossless conversion of TEXT to INTEGER or REAL is not possible then
>   the value is stored using the TEXT storage class. No attempt is made
>   to convert NULL or BLOB values.

This indicates that sqlite will attempt conversions between types, and if the first 15 digits of the number can be converted and reversed, the numbers are deemed to be equal.  This effectively puts a limit on the available precision with which a number can be stored to 15 significant digits.

The [wikipedia article on double precision floating point numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)  has additional information which is useful when dealing with floating point numbers.